# Restarting hot_standby replication when the *slave* fails

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Context: master-slave replication on Postgres 9.4, slave died a couple of weeks ago:

- the slave copied a WAL-File from the master,
- told the master that the file is copied,
- the master deleted the wal-file,
- the slave tried to play the corrupt wal-file,
- found that the file is corrupt,
- and gives up to start up.

In the meantime the master have accumulated more logs than the database itself.

How can I tell master that the replication is over (to reconfigure the replication)? Any general comments how to proceed with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using a replication slot.  It is causing the master to retain the log files, because it still thinks the replica will be needing them.  (That is the purpose of a replication slot).  [Find the slot and delete it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-REPLICATION).  Then create a new one for the new replica you will need to seed.

Comment: pg_replication_slots view reported no records. The archive kept growing

Comment: (1) Is it the WAL archive or pg_xlog that is growing and (2) what is your archive command setting?

Comment: If you have an archive, the replica should be able to get the missing log file from the archive.  Why isn't it?  Can you tell from the replica's server log file?  If the replica is supposed to be cleaning the archive with `archive_cleanup_command` and it isn't, that would explain why the archive keeps growing.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots` is empty. The WAL archive directory keeps growing. I am not sure the `archive_cleanup_command` is here relevant, because it is never executed (one of the prev. WAL segments was corrupted, and does the slave db never gets into the step where the clean up command is being executed). The replica had gotten the file, asked to delete the file from the master (which happened successfully), but due to an error in the wal segment, the slave is in unrecoverable state.

Comment: When you say "WAL archive", do you mean `pg_xlog`, or do you mean the archive directory specified in the `archive_command`, `restore_command`, and `archive_cleanup_command`?

Answer (score 0):

`pg_archivecleanup` command on some operating systems (e.g. Windows Server) and NAS configurations may be falsely instructed that the file cannot be deleted in some of its internal checks (although the file permissions allow to delete the file), although if the checks are internally omitted, the file is successfully deleted.

This solves some of the issues I asked, it is not yet clear how to "unregister" a standby slave. If the slave is gone `SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots` is empty. If one reinstalled a replication, one might need to increase `max_wal_senders`, as one connection continues to be used by the "old" replication.